# Angular CLI does not reload when editing component html?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ubuntu, angular-cli

I'm running the app with `ng serve -o`.  If I edit `styles.scss` and hit save then the app live reloads, but editing components (TS or HTML) does not trigger a reload.

No errors show up in in the developer console or in the CLI.

Thoughts?

Comment: which OS you're working in?

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075661/error-user-limit-of-inotify-watches-reached-extreact-build.

Comment: @FatemeFazli you dam man!!  Ooops - I mean Woooman!!  That was it.  I had to increase the inotify watches.  Please provide that as the answer and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of limit of inotify watches and extra files will not be observed, you should increas amount of it.

For Debian, RedHat, or another similar Linux distribution, run:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

For ArchLinux, run:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system
```